# Issue with New-AzStorageDirectory -Directory "" -Path ""

Tags: powershell

$directory = New-AzStorageDirectory -Directory $parentDirectory -Path $directoryName
I am getting below error-

New-AzStorageDirectory : Cannot bind parameter 'Directory'. Cannot convert the "" value of type "System.String" to type
"Microsoft.Azure.Storage.File.CloudFileDirectory".
At C:\PROJECT\EngagePowerShellScript\StorageAccountFileShare.ps1:67 char:41

- ```
    New-AzStorageDirectory -Directory "" -Path ""
  ```
- ```
                                      ~~
  ```

  - CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [New-AzStorageDirectory], ParameterBindingException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Storage.File.Cmdlet.NewAzureStorageDirectory

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Directory needs to be of the type CloudFileDirectory so its not a string. In your case if you are creating a root directory you dont need to specify that parameter.

New root folder:

```
New-AzStorageDirectory -ShareName "ContosoShare06" -Path "ContosoWorkingFolder"
```

-Directory
Specifies a folder as a CloudFileDirectory object. This cmdlet creates the folder in the location that this parameter specifies. To obtain a directory, use the New-AzStorageDirectory cmdlet. You can also use the Get-AzStorageFile cmdlet to obtain a directory.

More information can be found in Microsofts Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storage/new-azstoragedirectory?view=azps-4.4.0